# How to return only ids from a FireBase query?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Here is the code I have. It currently returns an array full of objects. How can i return an array full of the object ids, instead?

```
    var ref = new Firebase('https://zip-it.firebaseio.com/zips');

    $scope.detectChangeDigit1 = function() {
        var query = ref.orderByChild("digit1").equalTo($scope.zipCode.firstDigit.toString());
        $scope.digit1Array = $firebaseArray(query);
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

A few of your JSON objects (add these to your question next time please):

```
  "20195": {
    "city": "ALTURAS",
    "digit1": "9",
    "digit2": "6",
    "digit3": "1",
    "digit4": "0",
    "digit5": "1",
    "population": "3969",
    "state": "CA",
    "zipCode": "96101"
  },
  "20196": {
    "city": "BLAIRSDEN-GRAEAGLE",
    "digit1": "9",
    "digit2": "6",
    "digit3": "1",
    "digit4": "0",
    "digit5": "3",
    "population": "1434",
    "state": "CA",
    "zipCode": "96103"
  },
```

You're using AngularFire, which builds on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK. That API will always load entire nodes, it has no option to only load object IDs.

To just get the IDs, you have a few options:

1. keep a separate list of only the IDs and load from that.
2. use the [REST API, which supports a `shallow=true` parameter](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-uri-params)
3. prevent the query altogether and add a list of IDs for each `digit1` value

Option 1 is tricky, given that you do an `orderByChild()`.

Option 2 will not work either, since you cannot combine `shallow=true` with other query parameters.

Option 3 is likely going to be most performant. You still have two sub-options in there:

- Store the entire objects under `digit1`:

  ```
  "by_digit1":
    "9":
      "20195": {
        "city": "ALTURAS",
        "digit1": "9",
        "digit2": "6",
        "digit3": "1",
        "digit4": "0",
        "digit5": "1",
        "population": "3969",
        "state": "CA",
        "zipCode": "96101"
      },
      "20196": {
        "city": "BLAIRSDEN-GRAEAGLE",
        "digit1": "9",
        "digit2": "6",
        "digit3": "1",
        "digit4": "0",
        "digit5": "3",
        "population": "1434",
        "state": "CA",
        "zipCode": "96103"
      },
  ```
- Store only the ID of each object under the "index":

  ```
  "by_digit1":
    "9":
      "20195": true,
      "20196": true,
  ```

With both these two structure, you can immediately access the list of items that you're looking for with:

```
ref.child('by_digit1').child('9')
```

With this last structure you'll then look up each city in the main list.

```
ref.child('by_digit1').child('9').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    var cityRef = ref.child('zips').child(child.key());
    cityRef.once('value', function(citySnapshot) {
      console.log(citySnapshot.val());
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: i see. i'm starting to think i may migrate this projects data to mongoDB. that might be a better fit. thank you for your help!